# How can I build script with an onEdit Trigger for a specific range, insert note in the cell, with timestamp?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets-api

I'm a beginner at coding so any advice or guidance would be entirely helpful. I'm working on a script that uses onEdit () for a specific range/column.

Once the onEdit () triggers with an if statement I'm assuming, a customized dialog prompt will appear to insert a note. After you type the note, it will tag the data validation you selected and insert it as a note on the cell with a timestamp.

Here's a sample sheet I made for this question:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12-b4pUK5xKqlLlOKvPxd-UZ__RaJMiEWXHPH5K9GvU4/edit?usp=sharing

Please feel free to ask questions!

```js
 
  
  function onEdit() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getActiveRange();
    var select = ss.getDisplayValue();
       if (select = 'Phone'){
    var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi(); 
    var name = Session.getActiveUser();        
    var cell = ss.getDisplayValue()
    var timestamp = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "EST", "MMM dd");
    var pnote = ss.getNote()
    Logger.log(timestamp);
    var result = ui.prompt(
      'Would you like to add a short note?',
      '',
      ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);
    
    // Process the user's response.
    var button = result.getSelectedButton();
    var text = result.getResponseText();
    var notes = [
      [pnote],
      [timestamp +": "+name + ": "+cell +": "+text+'.']
    ];
    if (button == ui.Button.OK) {
      // User clicked "OK".
      ss.setNote(notes);
    } else if (button == ui.Button.CANCEL) {
      // User clicked "Cancel".
      ui.alert('You did not set a note.');
    } else if (button == ui.Button.CLOSE) {
      // User clicked X in the title bar.
      ui.alert('You closed the dialog.');
    }
         
    }     else {
        Logger.log("Cell was out of range");
    }
  }

//Attempt 2 (no luck) would replace the first portion of script up to if statement.
//    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getActiveRange();
//    var column = ss.getColumn();
//    var actionColumn = [3]
//    
//    if (actionColumn.indexOf(column) = 3){
```

My question is how can I get this script to be triggered only when a data validation is selected in a specific column. Maybe the next work in could be having multiple if statements to customize the dialog questions & notes.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to have an if-condition inside onEdit that checks for the number of row, column.

For example you only want the onEdit to trigger on cell F5 (5,6), you can do:

```
function onEdit(e){
    var range = e.range;
    if(range.getRow() == 5 && range.getColumn() == 6){
        range.setNote('ROW: ' + range.getRow() + " COLUMN: "+ range.getColumn());

      //additional code . . . Do what you want..
    }
}
```

Just modify the code for other cells,columns,etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `e` parameter of the onEdit trigger. [Read about event objects here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#google_sheets_events)

Add the `e` parameter to the function and then use an `if` statement to check if the edit happened on the specified column of the specified sheet.

In this example the `if` is true if the edit happened on column B, col B is index `2` of `Sheet1`.

```
function onEdit(e){
  if(e.source.getSheetName() == "Sheet1" && e.range.getColumn() == 2){
```

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property "source" from undefined. (line 2, file "Code")Dismiss

Comment: My mistake. After setting up the trigger, I got it to work. Thank you for your help!